Why does the airflow turn less when you extend further from the body?
In this answer, it says as follows:

Because "far enough" from the Concorde's nose, the path followed by the airflow is not affected by its presence and it's just a straight line. Close to the nose we need a shock wave at 45° to make the airflow turn the 15° of the nose. Anyway, a bit further, the flow turns a bit less than 15° (let's say 10°) and therefore a shock wave of 40° is enough to achieve this inclination

Why is the flow allowed to turn less further from the body, or the Concorde in this case? What changes further from the body to allow the flow to turn less?
I don’t really understand why

"far enough" from the Concorde's nose, the path followed by the airflow is not affected by its presence and it's just a straight line

This fact would change the flow turning angle. The shock needs to turn a set angle unless it is changed.
The explanation might be talking about the 3D relieving effect, but I don’t think so because that would make the explanation false for 2D objects.

Imagine the plane "flies" through a dense stack of flexible pipes, filled with air. Normally, the pipes would fill up all of the available volume. So how would the additional volume of the airplane fit in?
First, turn things around to simplify them: Imagine that the air in the pipes is moving at airspeed while the aircraft is stationary. Now you take the position of an observer moving with the airplane. The physics is the same, only your point of view has changed.
The answer is: By reducing the diameter of the pipes locally in the vicinity of the airplane! In subsonic flight this happens by acceleration of the air, so the air in the pipes around the plane flows faster, taking up less space. Once the airplane has passed (to be precise, when its cross section narrows down towards the tail), the air in the pipes assumes its old speed and the pipe cross section will increase back to its initial value.
In supersonic flight, things turn around because now the change in density dominates the pipe cross section: Compression shocks will not only slow the air down, but also compress it so much that the pipe cross section shrinks.  That shrinkage might require that several pipes away there is still some shrinkage required, but if the air in enough pipes is compressed, enough volume has been freed up for the airplane to fit in. The pipes farther away do not need to shrink and can stay at their initial density. In other words, the strength of the shock has died down to a value where no further density change is necessary anymore.
In reality, the density change will die down with the square of the distance from the airplane, but never disappear completely. The presence of the airplane does affect all the pipes, but this effect will be so small at a distance that we can assume as a good approximation that the presence of the airplane is not felt anymore.

I see. So basically the density changes will change the pipe(s) cross section enough around the aircraft which will also change the angle (and also therefore strength) of the shockwave? (and when the presence of the plane isn't felt anymore, this changing of shockwave angle will stop)

@Wyatt The shock angle at a distance is determined by the Mach number. Close to the airplane it is a combination of Mach number and contour. For air to speed up and density to increase you need an expansion fan.

"The shock angle at a distance is determined by the Mach number. Close to the airplane it is a combination of Mach number and contour." That's exactly what I've actually been trying to figure out (figure out why this that is the case), but I couldn't effectively explain it. (I wonder if that would require a separate question)

@Wyatt How far will the airplane have moved when the pressure change it produces reaches a point in the surrounding? Just think how far that pressure change can travel in the same time the plane travels. Make a sketch of it and look at different timesteps. That should help in understanding.

I think I see where you’re coming from. The pressure variation can’t travel faster than the speed of sound away from the aircraft, so it’s forced to be at a certain angle. Thanks for helping me figure this out!

Just to really make sure I have this correct, because in the past I have marked the question as 'solved' in my head when I was incorrect: According to the oblique shock chart, at Mach 2 the Mach cone will be 30°. A deflection of 5° will make a shock of ~34°. This 34° would be greater than the 30° of the Mach cone. But because of the effect you mentioned about how fast the disturbance can travel outwards, it would force the 34° shock to be 30°, AKA the same angle as the Mach cone. Is this correct?

@Wyatt Of course not. The air is deflected by 5°, so it does not flow in the same direction as before. With that new direction, the Mach angle will become wider when seen from the outside. When you place yourself as an observer inside that new flow direction, the Mach angle will still be 30°.

Just to firstly make sure I have the numbers right, in the end with the scenario I described the Mach cone would be 34° and also the shockwave? (I’m thinking the Mach cone would be 34° because if it is still 30° relative to the new already turned flow, then it’d be at a greater value relative to the original flow) That might not make sense, understandably, but I believe I could explain it in a dedicated comment.

@Wyatt The oncoming flow is irrelevant for the shock cone. It is the flow past the shock and its flow direction which is relevant. And a Mach cone is defined by its shockwave. They are the same thing, essentially.

Ah, I think I now understand what you mean. Again, thanks a lot. (Sorry for the late reply!)
